# Adding a button or text link to a content's view (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I would like to add a link or a button to my content's main view (I.E. ?q=node/120) that will redirect the user to a java applet that the node already has a reference to.

Is there an easy way to add such a button or link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this in hook_node_view.

Answer (score 0):

try it in reverse mode, this mean add your `custom field` as 'exclude from display' then add the `content:link` and use REWRITE RESULTS -> Rewrite the output of this field and put the pattern matching your custom field.
ex: [my_custom_title].
HTH